# ActiveRecord belongs_to through when using namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

My system is going to be large, so I've separated the models in namespaces. However, there is a model which I cannot setup the relation...

(My models are in portuguese, and the plurals are ok)

```
class Sistema::Instituicao < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :agencias
  has_many :dependencias, through: :agencias
  #(...)
end

class Sistema::Agencia < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instituicao
  has_many :dependencias
  #(...)
end

class Sistema::Dependencia < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agencia
  belongs_to :instituicao, through: :agencia
  #(...)
end
```

But I get an error in Dependencia, as follows:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key: through
```

What am I not seeing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the [api for belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) you will see that there's no `:through` option. the `:through` option is only available for `has_one` and `has_many` associations

Comment: Just replaced bolongs_to ==> has_one!! Thank you very much.